# Why Android Notification not works if setSmallIcon is Missing?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-notifications

My doubt is why Notification is not build if setSmallIcon is missing in code :

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
//  builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com/"));
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        builder.setContentTitle("Google");
        builder.setContentText("Go to Google");
        builder.setSubText("Tap to go to link in notifications.");

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
```

app dont throws any Exception, code run's fine but Notification is not showing and if i uncomment

```
builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

app Notification Works fine so my Question is why `builder.setSmallIcon` is compulsory to show a Notification.
And if I don"t want to show smallicon on status bar any Solution ?

Comment: how would the notification display if you do not have an icon in the statusbar??

Comment: @jim my question is this only is it possible to show notification in notification tile only without showing any icon on status bar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because `.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);` it's an pre requirement. If you're using `NotificationCompat.Builder`. I read some where in Google Developers Blog.

Comment: Ok, then if i missed builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher) in my code why code compile and run fine but not notify that i missed to set icon. Is it a bug ?

Comment: @kapilrajput men compile it's fine but it never check `what's pre-requirement in builder?`